# How to prevent alertview from rotating on IOS 8 orientation change

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios8, uialertview

I am making an application for IOS 8 platform using cordova & Xcode 6. I installed a cordova plugin called [org.apache.cordova.dialogs]. My app is meant to be work in portrait mode. Now the problem that I am facing is, When the device is rotated, the app stays as portrait itself , but the alertview rotates. It works fine with IOS 7. Is there a way to solve this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

in your config.xml and that should sort it, that will tell the OS to not allow any part of the app to rotate to landscape.